# Numpy version of this for loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use a built in numpy function to compare 2 arrays of pixel coordinates from a 3D image(ndarray), to see which points with a particular flag in image1 have a specific flag at the same coordinate in image2. Image1 and Image2 are the same size (both masks over an original 3D image). Right now I am using a for loop to compare which is quite inefficient. Is there a numpy method or a more efficient method to do this? I am unsure if I need to column stack as I have done below.

Code:

```
array1 = np.where(image1 == label1)
array2 = np.where(image2 == label2)

coordinates = []

temp1 = np.column_stack((array1[0],array1[1],array1[2]))
temp2 = np.column_stack((array2[0],array2[1],array2[2]))

for i, element in enumerate(temp1):
        if element in temp2:
            coordinates.append(element)
```

Comment: Depending on what you need, you might consider intersect1d

Comment: What do you mean by special flag? I

Comment: @Abel I couldn't figure out how to do row-wise comparison while using intersect1d, which flattened and gave intersection of individual elements. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna These are 3D uint8 numpy arrays generated by reading an image stack and applying a mask over them. Flag = pixel value at that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcast comparison:

```
comp = temp2[None] == temp1[:, None]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
comp = np.array([[a1 == a2 for a2 in temp2] for a1 in temp1])
```

Then use `ndarray.all` and `ndarray.any`:

```
comp.all(-1).any(0)
```

Test:

```
>>> r = np.random.rand(20, 3)
>>> a1 = r[::2]
>>> a2 = r[:10]
>>> (a2[None] == a1[:, None]).all(-1).any(0)
array([ True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True,
       False])
```

## Note:

For numpy arrays, it is incorrect to use keyword `in` to find whether a 1d array is a row of a 2d array, it is equivalent to judging whether any number in 1d array is in 2d array:

```
>>> a2d = np.random.rand(3, 3)
>>> np.array([a2d[0, 0], np.nan, np.nan]) in a2d
True
```

Comment: This works perfectly from a technical standpoint regarding my question in using numpy operations. But interestingly the runtime is longer (2m36s vs 30s for dataset tested).

Comment: @Ryuk909 In terms of the speed of comparison, this operation is very fast, but in order to obtain complete intermediate results, it will not use short circuits (and `ndarray.all` and `ndarray.any` will not use short circuits too), resulting in a lot of useless work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate, but using list comprehension makes it faster

```py
mask = [ (element in temp2) for element in temp1]
coordinates = temp1[mask]
```

Comment: Thanks. Runtime was 54.6s using for loop and 54.3s using list comprehension. I could not see a significant difference across multiple repeat runs but maybe the advantage will show up for a larger dataset.